# Why does Django CMS doc'n example Hello Plugin add <projectname_> prefix to hello model class on render causing error?

Tags: django-cms

I am trying to replicate the Hello plugin example in the Django CMS documentation here:  http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html

In the CMS, I can see and add the HelloPlugin, but when I press save, I get:
Exception Value:  no such table: DEC_hello   ('DEC' is my project name)

I have copy/pasted the code from the doc'n into models.py and cms_plugins.py and hello_plugin html.

I know it is normal in models.py for regular (models.model) classes/tables to be added to the database prefixed with the project name.

But class Hello(CMSPlugin) is not creating a table in the database.  I assume it is 'different and should not be added to the db at all as a table, and certainly not named DEC_hellow.

I have saved all these .py files and run makemigrations and migrate several times with no changes found/made.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Running Django CMS 3.6.0, Django version 1.11.20 Python 3.7.3  running on Windows 10

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin

class Hello(CMSPlugin):
    guest_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Guest')
```

cms_plugins.py

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import Hello

@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class HelloPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = Hello
    name = _("Hello Plugin")
    render_template = "hello_plugin.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(HelloPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

hello_plugin.html

```
<h1>Hello {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name}}
{% else %}
  {{ instance.guest_name }}
{% endif %}</h1>
```

Error on clicking save to add the plugin in CMS:

```
OperationalError at /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/
no such table: DEC_hello
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/?placeholder_id=41&plugin_type=HelloPlugin&cms_path=/en/purpose-list/&plugin_language=en
Django Version: 1.11.20
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: DEC_hello
Exception Location: D:\dev\djangocms\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 328
Python Executable:  D:\dev\djangocms\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\dev\\djangocms\\StoneProj',
 'D:\\dev\\djangocms\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\dev\\djangocms\\DLLs',
 'D:\\dev\\djangocms\\lib',
 'D:\\dev\\djangocms\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\dad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\dad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'D:\\dev\\djangocms',
 'D:\\dev\\djangocms\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 13 May 2019 14:01:15 -0400
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, finally.  Simple.  I needed to run 
python manage.py makemigrations and ...migrate with my App name (DEC, in my case) option.  Otherwise, these functions only performed on the base django cms system/admin data elements.